# How to efficiently parse a large JSON file (40mb) in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am currently trying to parse a large JSON file that is over 40mb. Currently, when I load the JSON in viewdidload(), it causes a memory spike up to 300mb. Is there a library or efficient way to parse this data so that it doesnt't cause memory spikes?

Current Code:

```
    if let url = URL(string: "JSON SOURCE") {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to fetch schools", err)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
                guard let dictionaries = json as? [[String: Any]] else {return}

              dictionaries.forEach({ (item) in
                    self.array.append(item["value"] as? String)
                })
                print(dictionaries)
            } catch let jsonError {
                print("Failed to parse JSON properly ", jsonError)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: If not even `Codable` helps you, I'm afraid there's not much you can do to reduce the memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to

- Split up the received data into smaller chunks, using paging
- Use autoreleasepools for huge arrays when parsing

There is absolutely no need to have that kind of amount of data in memory at once.